# Metaprogramming: method that works like "def"

Tags: ruby

I'd like to define a singleton method for a class object that works just like `def` but also does some other stuff. Inheriting classes can use that method like def without having any other special syntax other than using the method name rather than `def`.

A concrete example will help. In the code I'm developing I want to mark certain methods as "alpha" or "beta". That way you can query a class object for which methods are normal, which alpha, and which beta. Here's how I do it currently:

```
# Person
class Person
  def self.states
    if not instance_variable_defined?(:@states)
      @states = {}
     end

     return @states
  end

  def self.set_state(method_name, state)
    states[method_name] = state
  end
end

# Guest
class Guest < Person
  set_state 'sender', 'alpha'

  def sender(param1, param2)
    # do stuff
  end
end

puts Guest.states
```

That last line outputs

```
{:sender=>"alpha"}
```

OK, that works. But what I'd really like is to be able to call a method that works just like `def`, but which can flag a method as alpha or beta. So the Guest class might look like this:

```
class Guest < Person
  alpha sender(param1, param2)
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

I'd rather not use a block, like as follows. Setting aside scoping and other issues, it just doesn't feel like it's defining a method.

```
alpha('sender') do |param1, param2|
  # do stuff
end
```

Is there a way to metaprogram such a thing?

Comment: I am almost certain there's not going to be a way to do it without a block / proc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't quite do what you want, because `alpha sender(...)` attempts to pass the value of sender through to the `alpha` method. This obviously can't work.

However, method definition does return the symbol name of the defined method, which you can then pass to your `alpha` method:

```
class Person
  def self.alpha(method_name)
    set_state method_name, "alpha"
  end
  # ...
end

class Guest < Person
  alpha def sender(param1, param2)
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

This will define `sender` and call `alpha(:sender)`, which will then invoke `set_state` appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attempting to do this with `def`, you could instead do this by emulating `public`/`private`/`protected`, something like:

```
module MethodState
  def states
    @states ||= {}
  end

  def current_state
    @current_state ||= :normal
  end
  private :current_state

  [:alpha, :beta, :normal].each do |method_state|
    define_method method_state do |*method_names|
      if method_names.empty?
        @current_state = method_state
      else
        method_names.each { |name| states[name] = method_state }
      end
    end
  end

  def method_added(method_name)
    states[method_name] = current_state
  end

  def self.extended(base)
    # all already defined methods are 'normal' state methods
    base.normal *base.instance_methods(false)
  end
end

class Guest
  def normal_method_one
  end

  def normal_method_two
  end

  extend MethodState
  alpha
  def sender(p1, p2)
  end

  beta
  def a_beta_method
  end

  def another_alpha_method
  end
  alpha :another_alpha_method

  normal
  def one_last_normal
  end
end

Guest.states # => {:normal_method_two=>:normal,
# :normal_method_one=>:normal, :sender=>:alpha,
# :a_beta_method=>:beta, :another_alpha_method=>:alpha,
# :one_last_normal=>:normal}
```